# How to detect missing dependencies for an executable?

Tags: installation, command-line

Looking at https://askubuntu.com/a/207750/23678 how did the author know which dependency was missing? Is there a generic way to look up the list of dependencies of an executables and which ones are missing?

**UPDATE**: I just noticed that noticed that https://stackoverflow.com/a/9082947/14731 used

> readelf -l [executable]

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked AskUbuntu question, the author knew which dependency was missing because he was trying to install a 32-bit application on a 64-bit Ubuntu installation, and, to quote him:

> some 32 bit libraries are absent in Ubuntu 64 bit.

So he needed to install them.

However, to answer your questions:

- How to detect missing dependencies for an executable?
- Is there a generic way to look up the list of dependencies of an executables and which ones are missing?

Yes, there is a way to detect missing dependencies or to get a list of them.

#### Detect missing dependencies:

The [package management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) `apt`, used in Debian-based Linux distributions, is a clever system, where it will automatically detect if currently installed packages have missing dependencies (even if you have installed them using `dpkg`, and not `apt-get`). Let's say that you've installed a package, without its dependencies, then the next time you execute `apt-get upgrade`, you'll get an error similar to this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 package1 : Depends: package2 (>= 1.8) but 1.7.5-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Indicating that `package1` depends on `package2`, and `package2` (namely, the newer version in this example) is not installed. Usually, to fix this, you execute the command `sudo apt-get install -f`, which instructs `apt-get` to attempt to retrieve and install the missing packages.

#### Look up the list of dependencies of an executable:

The `apt` suite, as well as `dpkg`, provides a neat way to list the dependencies of a package.

- For `apt`, the command is:

  ```
  apt-cache depends <packagename>
  ```

  This will check the package in the repositories and list the dependencies, as well as "suggested" packages. If you really want to filter out the dependencies alone, you could filter the output by doing this: `apt-cache depends <packagename> | grep Depends`. Here's an example output:

  ```
  alaa@aa-lu:~$ apt-cache depends vlc
  vlc
    Depends: fonts-freefont-ttf
    Depends: vlc-nox
   |Depends: libavutil51
    Depends: libxpm4
    Depends: zlib1g
    PreDepends: dpkg
    Suggests: videolan-doc
    Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify
    Recommends: xdg-utils
    Breaks: vlc-data
    Breaks: vlc-nox
    Replaces: vlc-data
    Replaces: vlc-nox
  ```

  <sub>Output is cut down for brevity.</sub>
- For `dpkg`, the command to run it on a local file is:

  ```
  dpkg -I file.deb | grep Depends
  ```

  `dpkg -I file.deb` returns a lot of information about this `.deb` file, so we filter it to only look at the dependencies.

Since [`apt` is actually just a front-end for dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/q/309113/52726), both these commands essentially do the same exact thing, they go look at the `.deb` file of the application to find out what dependencies it needs, except `apt-cache` will look in the repositories. These "dependencies" are listed **inside** the `.deb` file as metadata, that is why even if you have manually downloaded and installed an application (which is usually a `.deb` file, so you'll be installing it using `dpkg` and not `apt`) from a website (for example, Google's Chrome browser from Google's website), `apt` will still find out that there are missing dependencies, by analyzing the installed packages.

---

I'm not well versed with all this computer architecture stuff, but in the case of Java in that question, it's really about the 32- and 64-bit architecture. To quote the answer from stackoverflow:

> You're running on a 64bit system without a 32bit runtime environment.

That specific library, that needed to be installed, was not included in the "Depends" part of the installation package, because he was installing a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system. So, extra troubleshooting was needed to find the culprit, hence the use of `readelf` and `ldd`. However, these are probably more specific to libraries, and remember that "dependencies" are not always "libraries", but could be other applications. So "***Is this the best approach?***", I doubt it; I think it's only best when extra troubleshooting is needed.

Comment: What happens if the executable did not come from APT? In the case of Java, the user had to download it manually from Oracle's website.

Comment: @Gili, I've edited my answer. It might not be the best explanation for that Java question, but I've tried my best.